# Shared run configuration in IntelliJ with modified classpath

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In our project, we share IntelliJ run configurations (using a git repository) with #IC-232.10227.8 (2023.2.5).
We have many run configs in the same IntelliJ module and one of them needs a different classpath than the module. Different means: *less* libraries than in the module dependencies.

Whenever we disable "Use classpath of module", apply and re-open the run configuration, the classpath is again set by the module. (The [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-java-application.html#more_options) keeps the explanation of this option rather short.)

This leads to a difficult situation:

- we cannot modify the classpath via excludes because of [IDEA-303236](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-303236/Relative-path-or-macros-for-modify-classpath-in-Run-Debug-configuration-settings) -> developers would be bound to using the same local base path
- we cannot modify the classpath via includes (even if macros work there) since the module classpath comes first - including is not the problem...

The only chance I see is to explicitly set the classpath via JVM command line argument (this overrides module classpath), which leads to a horrific non-maintainable single-liner

`-classpath=/path/to/first/lib;/path/to/second/lib;...`

Do we oversee something? It seems a flaw that IntelliJ cannot handle shared run configs with non-module classpaths.

Comment: There is no way to disable the "Use classpath of module" in Application run configuration. That option only hides/shows that UI in the run configuration. In IntelliJ, each Java program is associated with a module concept and needs a module for running so the IDE knows where the source code is located for compilation before running and what libraries it has. For your case, you need to create a module with fewer libraries and create another module including it to add other libraries. This is similar to if you run a Maven/Gradle project from the command line with a different set of libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible unless the bug mentioned in the question is resolved. In IntelliJ, each run configuration is associated with a module (according to LJ replica's comment) and to create an additional module is not a solution in our case, since our modules are connected to git repositories.